# Knockoutjs: working with existing data

Tags: javascript, textarea, knockout.js

here is the code:

HTML:

```
<textarea data-bind="value: MyText">
    Hello world
    line 2
    line 3
</textarea>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = 
{
    MyText : ko.observable()  
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HSfuq/

Textarea becomes empty, because of `ko.observable()`, but how can I save existing value in textarea?

I have big multiline document in textarea (from database), and I want to edit it with features of Knockoutjs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't extract the text from HTML, just make your view model like this:

```
var viewModel = {

    MyText : ko.observable("I'm the data from the server")  

};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HSfuq/1/
I would prefer the first method.

Or you can extract the text from the html like this, if you must do so:

HTML:

```
<textarea data-bind="value: MyText" id='textareaID'>
    Hello world
    line 2
    line 3
</textarea>
```

JS:

```
//using jQuery, but you could do this otherwise as well 
var texareaText = $('#textareaID').text();
var viewModel = {

    MyText : ko.observable( texareaText )  

};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HSfuq/2/

Or use JSON serialization (any way you like, `return JSON(yourDataIncludingMultiLineText);` from MVC controller action, or a serializer library like Newtonsoft JSON.net http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Newtonsoft.Json) to serialize the multi line text.

Comment: Hm. Of course I know about this. But document is big and multiline. 
Can you provide an multiline example with support of `"`?

Comment: Thanks for example, but I thought there is native support of this in knockoutjs :)

Comment: In KO, your "source" of anything is your view model. If something is not in the view model, it "doesn't exist"

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery, it would be something like this:

```
var viewModel = {
    MyText : ko.observable($('textarea').val())
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```